# Document library to show only folders to user

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any logic that we can implement for SharePoint library to show only folders in it and items should not be visible to the user.

The real requirement is that the document structure is like  RootFolder1 --> ChildFolder1 --> documents.

It is like a person can upload document but he can not see documents in this library. Also he has to upload document to a specific folder.

So, I think I have to do it using custom coding, is there anything OOTB?

Comment: just for my curiosity ... why would i not like to show documents inside folders ?

Comment: What if you set permission for library such that user can see only documents uploaded by him/her.. ??

Comment: @Monica, A kind of application is needed just to upload document and the user should not traverse to the folder and see the other documents already updated as documents are confidential. So I was thinking if it can be implemented OOTB

Comment: what abou using a drop off library? use adds them there, and they get moved elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

Just change the view to only show the items when `Content Type = Folder`.

Be aware that you would need to create a custom permission group so the users can upload documents, but not be able to create/switch/modify views.

Answer (score 4):

In your view add condition - "Content Type = Folder". This will satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of permission policy would cause a **horrible** administrative task for the ones trying to keep the SharePoint site nice and tidy. Yes, it is possible to add the kind of unique permissions that only a folder within a library is visible to a user, but none of the files is visible. I don't want to get into how - you simply do not want to have unique permissions for each file in a library. You don't.

The existing answers detail how you can add a view for this, but technically users would still have permissions to the files, and to any other possibly existing views which may directly list the files in that particular location. Therefore I would **not** recommend hiding items with filter-options of views.

Instead of user permission chaos, you indeed should consider some of the suggested ideas from the comments:

1. In the library, set that users can only see the files uploaded by them
2. Use Drop Off Library, which lets users to "drop off" their files to a library, which are then automatically moved to their intended location (based on e.g. metadata or whichever properties you prefer)

The mentioned are the most simple, yet powerful ways to do this OOTB. I'd go with the 2nd option.